# copy file from container to the host before the container dies

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, openshift-origin

I am pretty novice to the docker container. I am trying to build an image which is running a jar file. I want to pass the output file to the host for further processing but the container exits as soon as it finish the command. 
1- what is the best practices for this problem?
2- is there any way to pass the file name dynamically instead of hard coding in the docker file.
here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mybase:latest
VOLUME /root/:/var/myVol/
EXPOSE 8080
ADD mydir/test.jar /tmp/test.jar
CMD bash -c 'java -jar /tmp/test.jar > /var/myVol/output.json'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just mount output file as a volume using -v option.  Your program will write directly to the output file on the host without any need to copy anything anywhere

Be aware however that `-v` option is known to be [extremely slow](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#known-issues).

Comment: Is there any way that my jar file read the file directly from the host? What changes needed in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Same thing just mount it as a volume  with -v `pwd`/yourfile.jar:/var/app/yourfile.jar